# Blazor client.dll not found 404

Tags: blazor

I have created a project in visual studio 2019 preview (Blazor-core hosted) and my current Dot Net version is 3.0.100-preview6-012264
when I run it shows `loading...` in the browser and I inspect chrome browser it shows following problem.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/naboK.jpg[image: Error Shows in the console when Blazor app run]

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Comment: ok, Sir, let me more specific  . 1. I create a Blazor client-hosted application with Visual Studio 2019 preview. 2. Then I build this project and run it with default code, I didn't change anything. 3. When it runs is the browser it shows only Loading text. 4. when I open chrome inspection tools it shows above errors in the console. 5. when I go to network tab there I found my client dll in not build and shows 404 error. 6. In the Console Tab, the assembly mscorlib.dll was not found or could not be loaded. the error happens in the blazor.webassembly.js file

Comment: [Edit] your question. And be specific about the platform(s) , the screenshot seems to be from a Jenkins build server (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this issue by installing new Dotnet  SDK 3.0.100-preview7-012821
and re-install visual studio 2019 preview and running this Blazor template command
dotnet new -i Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates::3.0.0-preview7.19365.7